# как отслеживать процесс копирования файлов в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

я написал скрипт, который копирует папки с файлами в другую папку(делает бекапы в общем)

```
#по сути это самая главная строчка в коде
shutil.copytree(FILES, (STORAGE + "\\" + saveName))
```

так вот, если FILES будет достаточно большим, копировать оно будет долго

вопрос: как мне отследить, как проходит копирование и когда оно закончится?

Comment: Прописать свой [copy_function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree)?

Comment: @andreymal а что в copy_function хотя бы примерно написать надо?

Comment: Примерно надо написать то, как хотите отслеживать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для copy_function можно сделать так.

```
def mycopy(src, dst, follow_symlinks=True):
    print(src,"→",dst, end='\r')
    return shutil.copy2(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)

shutil.copytree(FILES, (STORAGE + "\\" + saveName), copy_function=mycopy)
```

Но тут сложно вкорячить процент выполнения. Читай документацию дальше и увидишь https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#copytree-example

В неё добавить индикацию в пару строк не сложно.

```
def copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, count=0, copied=0):
    names = os.listdir(src)
    count += len(names) #раз
    os.makedirs(dst)
    errors = []
    for name in names:
        copied += 1 # два
        print(src,"→",dst, f' {int(100*copied/count)}%', end='\r') # четыре
        srcname = os.path.join(src, name)
        dstname = os.path.join(dst, name)
        try:
            if symlinks and os.path.islink(srcname):
                linkto = os.readlink(srcname)
                os.symlink(linkto, dstname)
            elif os.path.isdir(srcname):
                copytree(srcname, dstname, symlinks, count, copied) # три
            else:
                copy2(srcname, dstname)
            # XXX What about devices, sockets etc.?
        except OSError as why:
            errors.append((srcname, dstname, str(why)))
        # catch the Error from the recursive copytree so that we can
        # continue with other files
        except Error as err:
            errors.extend(err.args[0])
```